# Sum Datatable values with same criteria

Tags: c#, linq, select, datatable

I have a data table and I need to merge the cells with the same values in the columns `IPC` and `Second Best Issuer` and sum the values in the columns `Dirty value PC` and `Par Value LC`. All the values are type string.

For example:
[image]

I'm a beginner with query and I'm looking for simple way to do this in C# with LINQ.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("IPC", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Dirty", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Second", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Par", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 5, "BB", 55 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 4, "B", 30 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 15, "AAA", 20 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 10, "BB", 80 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 20, "AA", 90 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 30, "AAA", 50 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 5, "B", 60 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 15, "AA", 70 });

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => new {ipc = x.Field<int>("IPC"), second = x.Field<string>("Second")}).ToList();


            DataTable dtsum = dt.Clone();

            foreach(var group in groups)
            {
                dtsum.Rows.Add(new object[] {group.Key.ipc, group.Sum(y => y.Field<int>("Dirty")), group.Key.second, group.Sum(y => y.Field<int>("Par"))});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you jdweng! Does it works even if all my data in the datatable are type of strings?

Comment: No since you are summing two columns.  You would need to cast string to integers to sum.

Comment: Thank you very much. Last thing if possible: 
if before the IPC column I have another column named "sector" that remains unchanged, how can i add it in the dtsum?

Comment: The columns are in order so add as first item to new object[] { group.FirstOrDefault().Field<string>("sector")